# iOS: Add ability to delete files from my app using system menu (Settings->General->iPhone Storage)

Tags: ios, file, system

I notice for some apps, you have the ability to delete data (stored) files from that app, using the system menu (Settings->General->iPhone Storage->AppName)

How can I add the ability to my app? Is it enabling permission, or do I have to write code too?

Answer (score 3):

You should make **both** of these raw keys `true` in the **info.plist**. then any files inside the `documents` folder will appear there.

```
UIFileSharingEnabled
```

```
LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace
```

they should be added like:

> [image: Demo]

Note that now the user can access the files directly without using your app. (with a computer or using the **Files** app or etc.)